# Why does my C# TestClass class complain (wrongly) that its parent doesn't have a parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, visual-studio-2012, tdd

I am doing some TDD in C# (Visual Studio 2012) using MSTest. 
I have a class declared with the `[TestClass]` attribute.
My test class inherits from the class I am trying to test.

The parent class has a parameterless constructor, and yet I am getting a build error

```
'RatingsClass.OutputLine' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

Here is my base class with its parameterless constructor:

```
namespace RatingsClasses
{
    public class OutputLine
    {
        public OutputLine()
        {
            Initialise("Parameterless constructor called");
        }
(and so on)
```

Here is the test class which inherits from the base class. This causes the following build error:

```
'RatingsClass.OutputLine' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

Code:

```
using RatingsClasses;

namespace RatingsKataV2
{
    [TestClass]
    public class RatingsTests: OutputLine
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestSingleTripRatingIs20()
        {
(and so on)
```

Also when I try to call the base class's parameterless constructor directly from the derived class's constructor, I get lots of red squiggly lines and syntax errors such as `Constructor must have body` and `Unexpected token`.

Here is my attempt to call the base constructor explicitly:

```
using RatingsClasses;

namespace RatingsKataV2
{
    [TestClass]
    public class RatingsTests: OutputLine
    {
        public RatingsTests(): OutputLine()
        {

        }
(the rest of the class goes here)
```

What am I doing wrong?

The reason I am doing it this way is that I would like to test the various private members of my base class are being populated correctly. Rather than provide getters and setters or make those members public, it seemed to make sense that my test class simply inherit from the class it is testing, so that it can directly access those private members. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you're getting "constructor must have body" and "unexpected token" (before you tried to explicitly call the constructor) then there's something else going wrong. Please provide a short but *complete* program which doesn't compile.

Comment: @JonSkeet: She gets that error for this line: `public RatingsTests(): OutputLine()` which obviously is incorrect.

Comment: Did you paste your code into the question, or type it?  I suspect that your base class has a typing error that you didn't repeat when typing up your question.

Comment: [Don't test private methods or properties!](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/05/31/my-take-on-unit-testing-private-methods) You need to understand the behavior/feature/functionality that uses them and test that.

Comment: Well, it turned out that I was getting ahead of myself in the list of build errors. There were earlier build errors in the list, which related to the base class: Once these were fixed, the code compiled. Lesson learnt! (and apologies)

Comment: Ryan, what if I want to make sure that after certain actions, my being-tested class has the correct inner state? Are you saying that I must only test the final result (which is not output until several discrete and testable inner steps have been undertaken)?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong for calling the base constructor.  You should use the `base` keyword:

```
public RatingsTest()
    : base()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The TestClass attribute is for classes that contain unit tests, not for classes that are the targets of those tests. By deriving from the target under test, you are also extending that target to RatingsTests.

RatingsTests should not need to inherit from OutputLine in order to test, but the constructor shoud read.

```
public RatingsTests(): base() {}
```

Comment: The reason the test class inherits from the class being tested is so that it can access the private members of that class. A bit like self shunting, I think?

Anyway, it turned out that all of these problems were caused by the fact that there were earlier build errors caused by problems within the base class. Once these were fixed, everything else worked too.

Lesson: Fix build errors one at a time, rather than scanning ahead and trying to fix later ones first!

Still, I would like an answer to whether inheritance is a good way for a test to access private members in the class you are testing?

Answer (score 0):

You use `base` to explicitly choose the constructor of the the base class that should be used:

```
public RatingsTests() : base()
{
}
```

However, this is unnecessary, because the parameterless constructor is the default one being used when this is omitted.

The first code you showed should work, so I guess that your actual code is different or you have a second class called `OutputLine` somewhere in your code base.

Make sure that you are using the correct `OutputLine` class and that this class actually has a `public` parameterless constructor. If `public` is missing, it is automatically `private` and can't be used by a derived class.